# maven plugin requires unused jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, raml

I am trying to use jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin in our maven project and can't understand why the plugin configured in one module requires a class from another module, which is not on the classpath.

I am trying to generate RAML for existing jersey controllers. We are trying to isolate our internal beans/DAOs, and we intentionally exclude internal Basket from the module that contains jersey resources. You will not find it using mvn dependency:tree.
However, when I try to build the module I am getting:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.4:generate-raml (default) on project bapi-api: Execution default of goal org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.4:generate-raml failed: A required class was missing while executing org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.4:generate-raml: com/somepackage/api/basket/Basket
```

Basket class is located in the module that is explicitly excluded from the classpath:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.neededmodule.bapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>bapi-transformer</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.modulethatcontainsbasketclass.bapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>booking-basket-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I have already reported it in [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs/issues/216), but the question to SO community is more general:

**How can a maven plugin ask for the classes that are not required by the module itself?**

Comment: You can add dependencies to every plugin separately by adding a dependencies section. You might want to generate raml for the basket api  separately from neededmodule, since the raml generator seems to include all raml deps when generating.

Comment: Good point about dependencies section, @AlexanderTorstling. However, I don't want this RAML plugin to know anything about basket api. Basket module doesn't contain anything related to JAX-RS/REST. This module should not be seen or known to outside world.

Comment: An educated guess is that you generated raml for Basket in the related module and that the plugin therefore tries to follow that link. That's why I suggestef generating separately.

Comment: I have only added jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin to one child module. Basket is a POJO. What RALM can be generated for that? This plugin is supposed to process JAX-RS annotations. Even if I did generate another RAML inside Basket module, how can the plugin figure it out without having that module on the classpath?

Comment: I don't know anything about RAML but I know from protobuf that if you genrate code for a sub-module, the protobuf plugin tries to look at the protobuf of the parent project and join it with the protobuf for the sub-module. So I'm guessing that you are seeing something similar.

Comment: Are you saying that protobuf plugin is scanning a parent module even though it is only specified in the child? Are you absolutely sure it is not mentioned in a parent of a parent or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, that is what happens with protobuf. But we're not getting anywhere. Post a minimal verifiable example instead and we can discuss around that.